# gradle: how to remove intermediate subprojects?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle project and I want to store all subprojects inside one dir: `testing`. My file structure is:

```
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
├── settings.gradle
└── testing
    ├── A
    │   └── build.gradle
    └── B
        └── build.gradle
```

and my `settings.gradle` adds those subprojects:

```
def testingDir = 'testing'
def absolutePath = rootDir.getAbsolutePath()
def testModules = new File(absolutePath + '/' + testingDir).list()
                                .each {println it}
                                .collect{testingDir + ':'+it} as String[]
include testModules
```

but when I run `./gradlew projects` it prints subdirectories correctly but reports `testing` as one of subprojects:

```
A
B
:projects

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'my-project'
\--- Project ':testing'
     +--- Project ':testing:A'
     \--- Project ':testing:B'
```

The question is: why `testing` is a subproject and how to get rid of it?

Gradle 3.3

Answer (score 1):

In `settings.gradle` instead of

```
include testModules
```

try:

```
includeFlat testModules
```

Comment: while this indeed removes the `testing` subproject, something is very wrong: top level test task doesn't run tests in subprojects (but report success), when i run test task in subproject if fails with `Project 'testing' is ambiguous in root project`

Comment: @piotrek, yes you're right. When `includeFlat` is used, the projects that are included need to be siblings of root.